# Why can't you define new types in a C++ template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm creating a library to allow OCaml/Haskell-like algebraic data types and pattern matching. The algebraic data types are implemented using a class similar to [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/variant.html). I would like to be able to define new types (the constructor) in the template arguments, but I get an error. I'm using my own type with variadic templates, but I'll use Boost's `variant` here for simplicity. Why isn't something like this:

```
typedef variant <
    class Foo { ... },
    class Bar { ... }
> Baz;
```

allowed? I know I can define the types separately, but that means I can't use some nice macros. In most cases in C++ you *are* allowed to define a new type where you are using it, for example:

```
struct Foo { ... } bar;
```

Here I am defining a new type `Foo`, and a variable `bar` of type `Foo`. If things like this are allowed, why doesn't it work with templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because template arguments are treated similar to function arguments and you can not declare

```
void func( class A{} a, class B{} b );
```

either. I also think it would be impossible to obey the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) if you need the classes in more than one template (typedef).

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't a reason why except for that it's not there and I guess it hasn't been proposed to be added, or if it has, didn't have enough support.

If you want to pursue it, I'd suggest starting with the standards committee

http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/

Answer (score -1):

I think coming [C++0x Concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Concepts) are pretty close, though not exactly the same to what you are describing.

Comment: That has nothing to do with this.